# Deleting environments from azureml studio

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

How may I delete an environment from azure machine learning workspace? I can create and list them but could not figure out how I may delete them?

Comment: Do you want to remove the environment metadata from the registry or remove the underlying docker images that are created on the ACR?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the listed item in the Environments tab of your Azure ML Studio, you can try the following command with your Azure CLI

> `az ml environment delete -n <environment_name> -g <Resource-group name> -w <Workspace name> -v <version of the environment>`

Answer (score 1):

Environments are versioned however, so you could just register over it with the new definition for now to "erase" consumers picking up the old one by default as a workaround (if you just wanted to reuse the name).

If you're interested in shortening the list of returned values, might be easier to use ws.environments["mysecondenv"] instead

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Environments cannot be deleted from the GUI.

Here's what worked for me:

1. From the CMD prompt, launch Azure CLI `az login`
2. Once you verify your subscription/ RG/ Workspace, list the available Environments using the command `az ml environment list`
3. Before deleting, it is a good practice to list the environment: `az ml environment list --name name-of-your-env`
4. Once the enviornment is confirmed, you can delete it by using the command `az ml environment archive --name name-of-your-env`

Please note there wont be any output generated if the deletion/ archiving process is successful.

Instead of `delete`, the `archive` command seems to work. For more info [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21957)

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean un-registering an environment because the environment itself dose not exist under your workspace, unless you build a container with this specific environment.

The answer is currently no. See here: https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1201

Same is with experiments and I thinks models as well. Makes sense to me actually because you track them all together.